# Where can I edit the contents of global: custom text

Tags: commerce

I'm using Commerce Kickstart for a while now, but I can't seem to show discounted prices in product lists. 
In my product displays, the discounted price is shown, as it's supposed to.

So I thought I just needed to change the field in the "Collection products" view. But this view uses a global: custom text field. I think I need to fix this in some tpl file, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

So, any tips on where I can change the selected fields for "Collection products"? 
Or any other tip on how to display discounted prices in the product lists an easier way?

(BTW, I'm using Commerce Price Savings Formatter module, not sure if this is relevant)

Comment: global: custom text is from views, so edit your view? Else, you will need to find the .tpl.php file that belongs to the view

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. How can I find out which tpl file is linked to that view?

Comment: tpl file should have the name of the view

Comment: Also, in Views, you could go under Advanced, and click on theme, and the bolded tpl file names are the ones being used.